# True Anomaly of Circular Orbit

Tags: orbital-mechanics, orbit, orbital-elements, stk-agi

How would you calculate the true anomaly of a circular orbit (e=0)? I'm trying to design an orbit for a mission on STK and so I'm not sure what the eccentric anomaly (in order to calculate true anomaly) would be since it's not a question about the orbital element at a particular time.

Answer (score 2):

For your own calculations, whenever you have a case of zero (or very small) eccentricity you may need to handle them differently and just choose an arbitrary *argument of periapsis*, perhaps zero.

What does "very small" eccentricity mean for you? Small enough so that it doesn't make a difference (your orbit doesn't deviate from a circle by more than your acceptable error) or so small that it causes other numerical issues.

Then just use $==2/$

[image: argument of periapsis and other stuff]

> Fig. 1: Diagram of orbital elements, including the [argument of periapsis (ω)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_of_periapsis).